# Angular 2: "Flow of information is uni directional" What does is mean?

Tags: angular

I am going through angular 2 training book of [Rangle.io](https://rangle.io/). I am trying to understand how changes detection works angular 2. In [this chapter](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/), author says that

> In Angular, **the flow of information is unidirectional**, even when using
>   ngModel to implement two way data binding, which is only syntactic
>   sugar on top of the unidirectional flow. In this new version of the
>   framework, our code is responsible for updating the models.

I want to know the meaning unidirectional flow of information means in angular 2 reference. Is it because of tree like structure of components? or it's something else. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that change detection only propagates found model changes from parent to children.

All changes in the other direction are done by events.

This way change detection won't ever have to deal with cycles where a parent updates a child, this update causes an update in the parent, this causes updated in the child ...

Even when there is a syntax for two-way binding, it's not actually two-way-binding but just syntactic sugar for property binding and event binding:

```
[ngModel]="prop" (ngModelChange)="prop = $event"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please share any link which explains angular 2 change detection simply. I mean all of the links talk about immutable and observable, not sure why people pull them into dialogue when we talk about change detection in angular 2.

Comment: Because `Observable` are like events, they actively notify subscribers about changes (push). Immutable objects work better with this data flow model, because updating an object passed previously might not be notified by a receiver. With immutable objects you need to use methods like observables to notify the receiver about changes. Otherwise I wouldn't expect a simple explanation about change detection Change detection isn't simple.